# IIS is not updated by Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

In Visual Studio, I have a MVC project. I need to use the local IIS, not the Express version. So I use "Use local Web Server" and I uncheck "Use IIS Express".

Then I click "Create Virtual Directory" button.

I get "The virtual directory was created successfully" message. Everything seems OK.

When I run the app, I get `"HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."` in the web browser.

If I go to IIS, the directory does not appear in the list.

I am lost, is it possible that Visual Studio is using another registry file or version to create the virtual directories? What tools can I use to track the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running Visual Studio as Administrator it won't be able to make changes to your IIS configuration.  If you need to use the full IIS, you can just create the virtual directory yourself in IIS Manager - you don't need to use the Create Virtual Directory button within VS.

Comment: I am running VS as Administrator. Also, I could create the directory from the IIS manager, but when I execute the app from Visual Studio, I get " HTTP 404. Resource not found"

Comment: Have you made your virtual directory into an application?

Comment: Yes, I clicked the "Create Virtual Directory" button under Properties. If I select IIS Express, everything works fine. The problem is when I try to use the local IIS.

Comment: A Virtual Directory is not an application.  Right click the Virtual Directory from within IIS, click Convert to Application.  Ensure the App Pool is set to the right framework version, and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I read it too fast. Yes, my directory is an application. By the way, I have found the problem. When I click "Create Virtual Directory" button, I expected that VS creates the virtual directory under the "Sites" category, but now I see that VS adds the virtual directory under Sites/MyOldWeb.  MyOldWeb was a old project that I built 2 years ago. I have no idea why VS add it in this place, probably due my lack of knowledge, but now I can see that it works fine.
Thank you